# I am getting an error while trying to connect with node using geth tool

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth, quorum

I am having an error while trying to attach to the quorum node, using the following command :--

geth attach --datadir new-node-1/geth.ipc

then I get this error

---

### Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix new-node-1/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or
directory

I tried to locate path of geth.ipc but nothing was there. I guess the file is not being created.

any suggestions guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be running the command like this (without --datadir):
geth attach new-node-1/geth.ipc

If that still doesn't work then make sure you have the correct path for the ipc file. Is `new-node-1` definitely the same path that was specified to the quorum node when it was started (i.e. with with `--datadir new-node-1`).

If the path is correct but `geth.ipc` file doesn't exist then the node hasn't managed to start up. Check the log file to see if there were any errors.

Comment: Yes , @Satpal thank you for explaining, I checked the raft node was not up.. and when I checked the node.log file for error. It shows the following .

'Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -raft

Comment: That implies you are running the upstream (original Ethereum) `geth` executable, instead of the quorum executable.
Check your path is set up so that you pick up Quorum `geth` before any ethereum executable. You can check this by running `geth version`. The result of this must contain a line with the text `Quorum Version`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below:

```
geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

It worked for me